# Check if Geopoint lies within GeoboundingBox

Tags: c#, uwp, geolocation, windows-runtime

The WinRT API knows both [Geopoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.geolocation.geopoint?view=winrt-19041) and [GeoboundingBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.geolocation.geoboundingbox?view=winrt-19041) classes. Is there an easy way to check if a `Geopoint` lies within a `GeoboundingBox`? This seems like an obvious thing to do but it seems this is something the framework does not support out of the box?

For a rectangle it might seem trivial, but its getting harder of the `GeoshapeType` is a `Geocircle` for example. Am I missing something here or do I need to start comparing long&lat values myself?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in API from GeoboundingBox class that could directly check if a Geopoint lies in it. So yes, if you want to check whether the point is inside the GeoboundingBox, you might need to get the long&lat values from the `NorthwestCorner` property and `SoutheastCorner` property of GeoboundingBox first. Then compare them with the long&lat values of the target point.